# I am receiving an 'unexpected { in {' message for my function - cannot see where this is or understand why the function won't work

Tags: r, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am hoping to group the variables from my data set into a pie chart. MY function is returning an error 'unexpected { in "{"'.

I would like the data to filter into 4 groups to then be plotted in a pie chart when the function is called.

I have tried opening and closing the while loop or moving the pie chart command.

```
data2<- read.csv("dataset1_r.csv", header = T, sep = ",")                 
head(data2)

mut1_func<- function(sex, age, mutation1, mutation2, exprs){
  a<-sex
  b<-age
  c<-mutation1
  d<-mutation2
  e<-exprs

  i<-1
  j<-200
  myresult2<-c()
  myresult3<-c()
  myresult4<-c()
  myresult5<-c()

  while (i<j){ ### while loop opens

    if (data2$mutation1[i] == 1 & data2$mutation2[i] == 1) {

      myresult2<-append(myresult2, data2$mutation1[i],data2$mutation2[i], i)

    } else if (data2$mutation1[i] == 1 & data2$mutation2[i] == 2) {

      myresult3<-append(myresult3, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)

    } else if (data2$mutation1[i] == 2 & data2$mutation2[i] == 1) {

      myresult4<-append(myresult4, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)

    } else (data2$mutation1[i] == 2 & data2$mutation2[i] == 2) {                            

      myresult5<-append(myresult5,data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)

    }

     x<-c(myresult2, myresult3, myresult4, myresult5)
  labels<-c("Both", "Mutation 1", "Mutation 2", "Neither")
  pie(x, labels)

}
```

Comment: You never closed your `while` loop (alternatively you never closed your function).  Add one more `}` at the end and your code should work (barring other possible errors).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Still receiving the same error message unfortunately

Comment: I am not buying that, unfortunately.  The message should have at least changed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenI have added a } at the end of my code and have received Error: unexpected '}' in "}". Which is indeed the same message as before. I'm not sure what you mean by not buying it?

Comment: @NelsonGon is there an alternative way to subset this information?

Comment: your last `else` statement should either be an `else if` or you need to remove the condition. And you need to a last } closure as @TimBiegeleisen said. I'm voting to close this question due to typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last else has this condition with no if `(data2$mutation1[i] == 2 & data2$mutation2[i] == 2)` so it looks like it gets confused.

Try this...

```
mut1_func<- function(sex, age, mutation1, mutation2, exprs){
        a<-sex
        b<-age
        c<-mutation1
        d<-mutation2
        e<-exp
        rs

        i <- 1
        j <- 200
        myresult2 <- c()
        myresult3 <- c()
        myresult4 <- c()
        myresult5 <- c()

        while (i < j) {
            if (data2$mutation1[i] == 1 & data2$mutation2[i] == 1) {
                myresult2 <-append(myresult2, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)
            } else if (data2$mutation1[i] == 1 & data2$mutation2[i] == 2) {
                    myresult3 <- append(myresult3, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)
                } else if (data2$mutation1[i] == 2 & data2$mutation2[i] == 1) {
                    myresult4 <- append(myresult4, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)
                } else  { #(data2$mutation1[i] == 2 & data2$mutation2[i] == 2)
                        myresult5 <- append(myresult5, data2$mutation1[i], data2$mutation2[i], i)
                    }
            x <- c(myresult2, myresult3, myresult4, myresult5)
            labels <- c("Both", "Mutation 1", "Mutation 2", "Neither")
            pie(x, labels)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions in the future, just vote to close.